# I'm receiving an "Account Suspended Page" when trying to accessing my VPS

Tags: cache, vps

I have a VPS account and host a handful of sites. Two of these sites I cannot view from specific computers. When I open the sites I get the account suspended page. See screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is what is odd. I only see it on two of my home computers. I also have a laptop at home that doesn't show it. If I look on my iPhone or iPad I do not see it.

All of these devices are on the same IP. So that makes it extra weird.

If I use a proxy I can in fact see the sites appear to be OK and are up online.

I've cleared my cache multiple times, even did a DNS flush and nothing.

So I'm wondering, why in the heck can I not view on my 2 specific computers?

Has anyone else experienced something like this before and know how to solve it?

Comment: I think you have misconfigured something in WHM...

Comment: Or your firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- restarting your web server
- clear your cache again
- flush your DNS cache again
- eventually, restart your DNS server
- reset your .htaccess file
- check if you have misconfigured something in WHM
- check your firewall rules
- try changing your home IP address if you have a static one
- eventually, try changing your VPS IP address
- eventually, move from ISP that provides your internet at home
- (*have you cleared your cache on the devices where the website DOES work? Maybe they're still showing the sites before they were suspended...*)

(Are you using a VPN?)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the .htaccess file under the account. At times, the redirect rule for the suspended page in .htaccess file keeps on showing this page.

An other alternative is to clear the cache OR restart apache.