# Why would my website not work for a handful of people only?

Tags: dns

I've just helped move a site from one server to another and updated the DNS servers and settings as well. It's been a month or more since the DNS changes, and has been working fine for *almost everyone* -- I have reports from 2 or 3 people that they can't access the site from home. ("This webpage is not available")

- They don't use the same provider -- one has Comcast and one has Brighthouse. However, the one with Comcast at home also uses Comcast at the office and it works at the office.
- A computer that can't access at their home can access from the office, so it's not the computer. A phone with Wifi enabled can't access it, but can access it immediately when Wifi is turned off.
- They've reset the cable modem already.

I'm stumped! Any ideas?

Comment: You said they reset the cable modem, but if they have a separate router (likely serving up wifi) they should power cycle it (not reset it as that will dump the config).

Comment: Yes, I meant rebooted, not reset, and their modem/router are one and the same in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pulling-out-of-hair, I got this message today:

> I logged into my router to check the DNS settings like we discussed. I just happened to click on security and noticed the "firewall" box was checked. I un-checked the box, clicked save, opened a new tab and entered our domain. Eureka! our site opened right up! It was my router.

Comment: +1, good to see it's fixed (even though it's almost a year later).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- restarting your web server
- clear your cache and the one of the people having trouble
- flush your DNS cache and the one of the people having trouble
- eventually, restart your DNS server
- reset your .htaccess file
- check if you have misconfigured something in your server
- check your firewall rules
- try changing the home IP address if you have a static one
- eventually, try changing your IP address
- eventually, move from ISP that provides internet at home

(Are you using a VPN?)

(From my answer on [I'm receiving an "Account Suspended Page" when trying to accessing my VPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69062/im-receiving-an-account-suspended-page-when-trying-to-accessing-my-vps/69085#69085))